# Issue setting up Docker on Windows 10 Home using WSL2

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows, wsl2

I am trying to set this up to be able to run a docker-compose setup on my Windows 10 Home with docker toolbox.
I need WSL2 to be able to do port forwarding from the Docker container, through WSL2 and access those services from my Windows browser.

I encountered an issue with Virtualization and Hyper-V:

1) After installing Docker Toolbox and WSL2, I ran the following commands to enable virtualization:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

That allows me to use the Ubuntu-18.04 App, but when trying to run the Docker Quickstart Terminal from the Docker Toolbox, I encounter the following error:

```
Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Raw-mode is unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V. (VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:01.902344 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking status on default´... Press any key to continue...
```

It seems its an issue due to having the Hyper-V enabled by default, so I removed it from the Windows Functionalities and also set the hypervisorlaunchtype using:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Now I can use the Docker Quickstart Terminal and the Docker VM runs correctly, however, now I cannot boot the Ubuntu-18.04 App since I now get the following Error:

```
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
```

Seems there is an option that I'm missing or perhaps due to the fact it's a Windows 10 Home edition?

I have already checked Virtualization is on from the BIOS directly, also restarted every time a change is made and I can either boot up the Docker VM or boot up the Ubuntu VM but not both.

EDIT:

OS and build> Microsoft Windows 10, V2004 [Version 10.0.19041.208]